# How to create a synchronized loop with async/wait

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to create a "synchronized like loop" with async await but I get the strange behavior of getting all the results after the first promise instead.

here is my test case. See how you get all together instead of print 1 by 1

```js
const p = () =>  new Promise((resolve) =>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
       resolve(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
   },1000)

})

const test =  () =>{

 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(async () =>{
      const e = await p();
      console.log(e)
  });
  
}

test();
```

Comment: map doesn't work with `aync / await`  But if you used say bluebird promise, it does have a promise based map.  Alternatively in your example a for-loop would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mention in comments, map is not Promise aware.  There are alternatives like `Bluebirds.map`,.. But the easy option is to use a for loop,..

Keeping to your example were your wanting to loop an array, you can use the `for of` variant too.  Changing to `for (let a = 1; a <= 10; a ++)` will work too.

eg.

```js
const p = () =>  new Promise((resolve) =>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
       resolve(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
   },1000)

})

const test =  async () =>{
 for (const a of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) {
   const e = await p();
   console.log(e)
 }  
}

test();
```

It's also worth pointing out bluebirds map has another trick up it's sleeve, it has a concurrency option.  This is very handy to prevent thrashing that can happen with `Promise.all`, you basically say you want to do `x` promises at a time, eg. you have 10 promises to do, but you find it's more optimal to do 3 concurrently.